# When do coordinate transformation preserve orthogonality?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, wavefunction, coordinate-systems

I'm wondering about the situation where you have two orthonormal wave functions,
$$ \langle \varphi( \vec{r_1}) | \psi ( \vec{r_2}) \rangle = 0 .$$
Under what restrictions would a coordinate transformation of one of the states, $ \vec{r_2} \rightarrow  \vec{r_2}+ \vec{R},$ preserve orthogonality?

$$ \langle \varphi( \vec{r}) | \psi ( \vec{r}+\vec{R}) \rangle = 0 $$
Intuitively, I think that translations would but rotations would not, but how do I formalize this? What class of linear transformations would it be and is there a way to construct a proof?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: 1. What do you mean by a coordinate transformation? QM doesn't really have "coordinates", after we quantize, we have *operators* $\hat{x}$ and $\hat{p}$ and states $\lvert \psi\rangle$, and you would have to formulate a transformation in terms of how it acts on operators or how it acts on states. 2. A rotation is not of the form $x\mapsto x+R$, you've restricted your transformations to translations simply by writing it that way.

Comment: Consider a 1d wavefunction $\varphi(x)$ that is non-zero only in the range $x\in[0,1]$ and a second wavefunction $\psi(x)$ that is non-zero only in the range $x\in[2,3]$. Clearly these two wavefunctions are orthogonal, but a translation of one of them need not be

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is the most general answer, but it is *an answer*. In the case of translations, let your orthogonal wavefunctions be eigenstates of the momentum operator, which generates translation. For example, take $\phi_{p_1}(x)$ and $\psi_{p_2}(x)$ to be two mutually orthogonal eigenstates of the momentum operator with eigenvalues $p_1$ and $p_2$, respectively
$$\int \phi_{p_1}(x)^{\dagger}  \psi_{p_2}(x) dx=0.$$

We want to find out whether
$$\int \phi_{p_1}(x)^{\dagger}  \psi_{p_2}(x+l) dx=0$$

is also true. Let's translate $\psi_{p_2}(x)\rightarrow \psi_{p_2}(x+l) = e^{i l \cdot \hat{p} } \psi_{p_2}(x)$. Since $\hat{p} \psi_{p_2}= p_2 \psi_{p_2}$, we can take out the eigenvalue out of the integral and thus orthogonality is preserved.

This argument can be generalized to eigenfunctions of the generators of any symmetry. So angular momentum eigenstates should remain orthogonal after rotation too.

To phrase it in the language in which you are asking the question, a *sufficient* condition would be that the generator of the transformation is diagonal in the basis of wavefunctions you are considering. I do not know about a necessary condition. Maybe someone else can point that out.

Comment: Why would eigenstates of the Hamiltonian also be eigenstates of the momentum operator? Isn't the simple harmonic oscillator a counterexample?

Comment: @Daniel  You're right. I misphrased that. I'll edit it. Thank you.